# SQL Server unpivot with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

Trying to get an Unpivot to apply across a few columns and am struggling to get it to work correctly. Maybe its not the right solution so definitely open to suggestions. Here's an example of my dataset

[Sample Data Set In Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGpqr.png)

[Sample Wanted Data Set In Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhW9D.png)

Sorry for the links, can't quite stick pics in these posts just yet.

Here's the code that I'm close to, it seems like I'm close...but maybe not.

```
SELECT 
    RunDate,
    ShipMode,
    Amt
FROM
    (SELECT
         CAST(sh.RunDt as DATE) as RunDt,
         sh.method1, sh.method2, sh.method3,
         sh.method4, sh.method5
     FROM 
         [dbo].sampletable sh
     WHERE 
         RunDt = '2016-10-17') AS P
UNPIVOT (
    RunDate FOR ShipMode IN(method1, method2, method3,method4, method5)
) AS Unpvt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a couple of names wrong.  You can unpivot using the SQL:

```
SELECT 

RunDt ,ShipMode ,Amt FROM (

 SELECT 
 CAST(sh.RunDt as DATE) as RunDt
,sh.method1 
,sh.method2 
,sh.method3  
,sh.method4 
,sh.method5
FROM [dbo].sampletable  sh
WHERE RunDt = '2018-10-17'

) AS P UNPIVOT ( Amt FOR ShipMode IN(method1, method2, method3,method4, method5) ) as Unpvt
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than UNPIVOT, another option is using a CROSS APPLY.  It offers a bit more flexibility

**Example**

```
Select A.RunDt
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('Method1',Method1)
                     ,('Method2',Method2)
                     ,('Method3',Method3)
                     ,('Method4',Method4)
                     ,('Method5',Method5)
             ) B(Overall,Amt)
 Where RunDt = '2016-10-17'
```